# Fit Image(s) in a liquid Parent

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to present an Image Slider in a liquid layout (parent) and I do not like to limit the height and with of the images while they can be requested by big screen monitors (27") to smalls one like 11" or even less.
Can you please let me know if there is plugin to help me to fix this issue?
Right now I am using a slider(plugin - Nivo) which has a fixed layout and I am not able to change it to  liquid
Here is the Code which I have:
HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>GALLERY</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="row_1">
 <div class="container"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="row_2">
 <div class="container">
 <div id="slideshow"> 
 <div id="slider"> 
 <img  src="img/1.jpg" title="" style="" /></div>      
 <img  src="img/2.jpg" title="" style="" /></div> 
 <img  src="img/3.jpg" title="" style="" /></div> 
 <img  src="img/4.jpg" title="" style="" /></div>      
 </div> 
 </div>  
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="row_3">
 <div class="container"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
 html{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
   }
 body {
  background-color: #272321;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%; 
  }
 #row_1 {
  position:relative;
  height:15%;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #row_2{
   position:relative;
   height:77%;
   width: 100%;
  }
  #row_3{
   position:relative;
   height:8%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #151110; 
   }
  .container{
   position:relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height:100%;
   width: 80%;
  }
```

Do you think if it is a good idea that I use several layouts for different screen size? Is there any way to fix this things with Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about pre-canned plug-ins, but it's not much of your own code to handle this.

You can attach an event handler to window resize, check the size of your container div and use your own javascript to select new image sizes for the slideshow based on the new container size.

Using a slight delay to prevent the code running hundreds of times during a resize, it could look like this:

```
(function() {
    var pauseTimer;

    $(window).resize(function() {
        // clear any previous timer running
        if (pauseTimer) {
            clearTimeout(pauseTimer);
        }
        // set new timer
        pauseTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            // user finished or paused resizing, 
            // so now we can recalculate slideshow size
            pauseTimer = null;
            // examine the size of your container div
            // select a new size image for your slideshow and load those images here
        }, 500);
    })
})();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Tucf2/

Comment: Thanks friend00 Is it Ok with you to let me know where I can find a sample for this?

Comment: @user1106951 - what do you mean "sample"?  I provided sample code for detecting the resize.  Resetting your slideshow to a new size is up to you.

Comment: Added a demo link to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the demo but it still not working on slider! can you please take a look at foloowing link and let me know what I am doing wrong?      http://www.ghazalphoto.com/G2_2/

Comment: @user1106951 - You have to make your own version of `setImageSize()` that works for all the images you are using.  What you have now isn't written to work with your slideshow.  If you want ask for help on how to dynamically change the size of a `jQuery Nivo Slider v2.1` plug-in and change the size of all existing images, then you should probably   start a new question that asks that more specific question.  This answer provides you the framework for knowing when things have changed size, but how to change the size of your slideshow is a different question.